# Cakephp return array for listbox with extra attribute

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to display listbox options in Cakephp that will have additional attributes.

For example:

```
<option value="1" dataval-price="5">one</option>
<option value="2" dataval-price="10">two</option>
<option value="3" dataval-price="50">three</option>
```

Have read elsewhere that this is just a case of building the array like so:

```
$options = array(
             2 => array('name' => 'One', 'value' => 1,  'dataval-price' => '5'),
             2 => array('name' => 'Two', 'value' => 2,  'dataval-price' => '10'), 
             2 => array('name' => 'Three', 'value' => 3,  'dataval-price' => '50')
);
```

How can I return data in this format? The helper below will return the data in a format that forces the listbox to instead use optgroups.

```
$optionsArray = $this->TableX->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('name', 'id', 'price'),
    'order' => array('name' => 'ASC')
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aliases for fields like so:

```
$results = $this->Model->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('name', 'id AS value', 'price AS dataval-price'),
    'order' => array('name' => 'ASC')
));
```

Your results will appear like this however:

```
array(
   0 => array(
        'Model' =>  array(
              'name' => 'name',
              'value' => 1,
              'dataval-price' => 2.00
        )
   ),
   //etc
);
```

This can be fixed using CakePHP's hash class:

```
$results = Hash::flatten($results);
$keys = str_replace('Model.', '', array_keys($results));
$results = array_combine($keys, array_values($results));
$results = Hash::expand($results);
```